# How to solve the limit:$\lim _{x\rightarrow - \infty}x+|x|^{\frac{2}{3}}(6-x)^\frac{1}{3}$

Tags: calculus, limits

$$\lim _{x\rightarrow - \infty}\{x+|x|^{\frac{2}{3}}(6-x)^\frac{1}{3}\}~=~?$$

I have no idea about it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us find for $a>0$ $$F=\lim_{x\to-\infty} x+|x|^m(a-x)^{1-m}$$

**Method**$\#1:$

Set $x=-\dfrac1h\implies|x|^m=\dfrac1{h^m}$ and $(a-x)^{1-m}=\dfrac{(ah+1)^{1-m}}{h^{1-m}}$

to find $$\lim_{h\to0^+}\dfrac{(1+ah)^{1-m}-1}h=a(1-m)$$

using [Binomial theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem)

**Method**$\#2:$

Set $x=-a\cot^2y$ with $0<y<\pi$  See [Principal values](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_trigonometric_functions#Principal_values)

$$F=\lim_{y\to0^+}a^m\cot^{2m}x\cdot a^{1-m}\csc^{2-2m}x-a\cot^2y$$

$$=a\lim_{y\to0^+}\dfrac{\cos^2y((\cos^2y)^{m-1}-1)}{\sin^2y}$$

$$=a\lim_{y\to0^+}\dfrac{(1-\sin^2y)^{m-1}-1}{\sin^2y}$$

$$=-a(m-1)$$  using [Binomial theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem)

Comment: Please pinpoint the mistake

Comment: lab.Perhaps too sophisticated for someone .+1)

Answer (score 1):

This one uses L'Hopitals rule.

\begin{align*}
\lim_{x \to -\infty} x + \sqrt[3]{6x^2 - x^3} &= \lim_{x \to -\infty} \frac{1 + \sqrt[3]{6x^{-1} - 1} }{x^{-1}}\\
&=\lim_{x \to -\infty} \frac{ -6x^{-2}(6x^{-1} - 1)^{-2/3} }{-3x^{-2}}\\
&=\lim_{x \to -\infty} 2(6x^{-1} - 1)^{-2/3} = 2 \end{align*}

Comment: The final result is false. Check on Wolfram Alpha.

Comment: Under the fraction line there should be $x$

Comment: Edited it, should be right now hopefully.

Answer (score 0):

Let's do things with positive numbers. It is equivalent to calculate the limit of $-y +y^{\frac{2}{3}}(6+y)^{\frac{1}{3}}$ when $y \rightarrow +\infty$.

We factor the expression: $y \left(-1 + (1 + \frac{6}{y})^{\frac{1}{3}} \right)$.

We use an asymptotic development: $(1 + \frac{6}{y})^{\frac{1}{3}} = 1 + \frac{1}{3} \frac{6}{y} +  o(\frac{6}{y}) = 1 + \frac{2}{y} +  o(\frac{1}{y})$ when  $y \rightarrow +\infty$.

Substracting $1$ then multiplying by $y$ the expression becomes: $y\left(-1 + 1 + \frac{2}{y} +  o(\frac{1}{y})\right) = 2 + o(1)$.

**Finally, the limit is $2$**.

Answer (score 0):

$y:=-x$; $y >0$;

$y^{2/3}((6+y)^{1/3}-y^{1/3})=$

$\dfrac{6y^{2/3}}{(6+y)^{2/3}+(6+y)^{1/3}y^{1/3}+y^{2/3}}$

$=\dfrac{6}{(1+6/y^{2/3})+(1+6/y^{1/3})+1}$;

Take the limit $y \rightarrow \infty$.

Used: $a^3-b^3=(a-b)(a^2+ab+b^2)$